# How can I check if a date is greater than the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 dates. Both are in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I applied a simple check that if

```
if ('2017-01-15' > '2016-12-15') { 
    return true; 
} else { 
    return false; 
}
```

But it is giving me a syntax error. What should I do?

Comment: share the error details and complete code

Comment: There is no error in the code that you gave, **it just works.** The problem must lie elsewhere, or the code here does not reflect your real code. Please investigate the exact cause of your problem and then edit the question to give real code and/or a better explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the format of the date string and your code structure, what you have should be working. If you're getting an error, check that it's coming from the section of code you've shown in your question.

That being said, you can improve the code by changing the strings to Date objects before comparing them. You can also shorten the code by just returning the result of the comparison. Try this:

```js
function dateComparison() {
  return new Date('2017-01-15') > new Date('2016-12-15');
}

console.log(dateComparison());
```

Comment: String comparison would also work here (in `yyyy-mm-dd` format)

Comment: @PranavCBalan very good point. The sample of code in the OP is syntactically valid too, so the problem must be elsewhere. I updated the answer

Comment: `return '2017-01-15' > '2016-12-15';` is enough

Comment: Thankyou sir. This was totally helpful.

Comment: @AliZia no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

As per the MDN

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

So you must be getting this error if you are not using the if condition within a function.

Answer (score 0):

Operators like `==, !=, ===, and !==` require you to use `date.getTime()` like this:

```
var x = new Date('2017-01-15');
var y = new Date('2016-12-15');  
var same = x.getTime() === y.getTime();
var notSame = x.getTime() !== y.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the moment.js library to help you achieve it:

```
return moment('2017-01-15').format('YYYY-MM-DD') > moment('2016-12-15').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert them to `Date` objects and then compare.

```
var dateStrA = "2017-01-15 00:00:00";
var dateStrB = "2016-12-15 00:00:00";

if (new Date(dateStrA) > new Date(dateStrB))
{
     ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comparing using equals, such as `===` will not work on `Date` objects. You can also use `Date.compare()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this...worked for me.
```

```js
    var startDate = "2019-03-23";
    var endDate = "2019-03-24";
    if(Date.parse(endDate) >= Date.parse(startDate)) {
     console.log('endDate is greater');
    } else {
     console.log('startDate is greater');
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.

Comment: sure, will take care of it. @chb

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
    if(d1.getTime()>d2.getTime())
```

Comment: You can't `.getTime()` of a string.